# pl/sql function to find those customers who are eligible for LOAN and the amount of loan

Tags: sql, plsql

Note: 
the question has 2 table: customer(id,name,dept,designation,salary) and account(id,ACCOUNT_NUMBER,FIXED
DEPOSIT) .
i wrote the pl/sql function for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loan_func (sal IN NUMBER,fd in NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER 
IS 
loan NUMBER(6);
BEGIN
IF (sal>60000 AND fd>100000) THEN
loan := (sal*0.4)+100000;
ELSIF (sal>50000 AND sal<59999 AND fd>50000) THEN
loan := (sal*0.3)+90000;
END IF;
RETURN loan;
END;
```

the function  in entered correctly but the cursor doesnot work! can you help me fix the problem to get the ans?

below is the cursor:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR CR IS
SELECT
    C_ID,
    A_ID,
    NAME,
    FIXED_DEPOSIT,
    SALARY
FROM
    CUSTOMER 
join ACCOUNT
on     C_ID = A_ID;
I CUSTOMER.C_ID%TYPE;
N CUSTOMER.NAME%TYPE;
fd ACCOUNT.FIXED_DEPOSIT%TYPE;
sal CUSTOMER.SALARY%TYPE;
Loan NUMBER(6);
BEGIN
OPEN CR;
LOOP
EXIT WHEN CR%NOTFOUND;
FETCH CR INTO I,N,fd,sal;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE(I || N);
Loan:=loan_func(sal,fd); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE(loan);
END LOOP;
END;
```

it shows the following error:

***ORA-06550: line 22, column 2:
PLS-00394: wrong number of values in the INTO list of a FETCH statement***

Comment: "wrong number of values in the INTO list of a FETCH statement": your `FETCH` statement has an `INTO` list with four variables in it, but your cursor selects five values.  With that in mind, the error is perhaps unsurprising. Looking at your code, you also have the `FETCH` and `EXIT WHEN...` statements the wrong way around, and have mistyped `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`: you're missing the `_` between `PUT` and `LINE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original query was correct. That used the ANSI JOIN syntax, the **preferred syntax**. The correction reverted to the an obsolete (since 1992 SQL standard), yet still supported syntax. The ON clause provides the same function as the *missing* statement.  
Your error is not necessary in the cursor but in the fetch. The cursor contains 5 columns, however the fetch only get 4 variables. Either c_id is not needed in the cursor OR you need to add it to the fetch. Even better would be switch to a **cursor for loop** where Oracle takes care the cursor handling.

```
declare
   loan number(6);
begin
   for cr in 
       ( select a_id, name,fixed_deposit fd, salary sal
           from customer c
           join account  a
             on c_id = a_id 
       ) 
   loop
      dbms_output.put ('id ='|| cr.a_id || 'name = ' ||cr.name n );
      loan:=loan_func(cr.sal,cr.fd); 
      dbms_output.putline(' loan amount is =' || loan);
   end loop
end;
```

I also corrected dbms_output statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
CURSOR CR IS
SELECT
    ID,NAME,FIXED_DEPOSIT,SALARY
FROM
    CUSTOMER C,
    ACCOUNT A
WHERE
    C.ID=A.ID;  <============================ missing ';'

I C.ID%TYPE;
N C.NAME%TYPE;
fd A.FIXED_DEPOSIT%TYPE;
sal C.SALARY%TYPE;
Loan NUMBER(6);
BEGIN
    OPEN CR;
LOOP
EXIT WHEN CR%NOTFOUND
FETCH CR INTO I,N,fd,sal;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE(‘ID = ||I||’ ‘NAME = ||N||’);
Loan:=loan_func(sal,fd); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE(‘LOAN AMOUNT IS =’|| loan);
END LOOP
END;
```

Comment: i corrected it but i got a new error........ORA-06550: line 22, column 2: PLS-00394: wrong number of values in the INTO list of a FETCH statement